# Let's design a nice badge icon!

Tags: discussion, badges

Most sites have a creative badge icon instead of the simple circle. Some examples (from Android Enthusiasts, User Experience, and Bicycles respectively):

[image: Badge Icons]

I think that Code Golf should also have a creative badge icon. What should it look like?

Comment: I'd tentatively suggest a golf ball, but the site's not *just* about code golf, so I think we need something representative of the full scope of the site.

Answer (score 5):

*Speaking as a user, not a moderator.*

I think Jin designs these for sites when they graduate. (I should ask him next time I have lunch with him.) Sure, you can provide input if you want, but I don't think they'll use community designs directly.

---

Update: PPCG is now undergoing [design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/13). We'll have most of the features of graduation, but the design will come later.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be possible the same way as the new site icon question posted recently.

Comment: Actually, as you have noticed, they haven't used that either. :-)

Comment: Hmm... I see. Do I have to delete this?

Comment: No, you can keep it around, at least you can see how many upvotes you get. ;-)

Comment: We've graduated now.

Comment: @CrazyPython No. At the time I wrote my answer, [design-independent graduation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/13) wasn't a thing; sites were thus taking forever to be graduated, because the design team was backlogged. Now, with design-independent graduation, sites could graduate quicker, but the design is still backlogged.

Comment: Community design can actually heavily influence the final design (ref: [worldbuilding.se])