# New badges for new design

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

There's an old (2014y) conversation about this: [Let's design a nice badge icon!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/lets-design-a-nice-badge-icon), but without any real outcome.

However, quite recently we got a new site design, including our new logo:
[image]

For me it looks like pretty good candidate for badge icon, because, you know, it's a medal.

Possible modifications:

1. Cut a strip a little bit (get rid of horizontal part).
2. Remove strip completely (and left only medal itself).
3. Make strip white (like done on meta).

What do you think about this idea?

Answer (score 6):

## I like option 2.

And actually, [it is already supposed to be so](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17778/43319).